# When can st_ino change for a direcory?

Tags: android, file, filesystems, stat, inode

I am trying to work with `StructStat` class in Android. As per android documentation at [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/StructStat#st_ino)

- `st_ino` represents File Serial Number of object
- `st_blocks` represents number of blocks allocated to this object

My query is

- Can `st_ino` which is a number, change for any directory/file, in any situation? or Would it be constant once memory is mounted.
- What does `st_blocks` returns, size of object means what value it has?

Thank you in advance